# How to answer a question that uses multiple tables without joins? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is there a way to answer this question without using joins?

Write a query that finds, for each customer X, another customer Y who has ordered at least one product in common with X. Find all such pairs of Customers (X, Y) and against each pair, the number of overlapping products. The query should thus have three columns. Order the results by the number of overlapping products.

The question uses the https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
database.

Using joins, I can answer the question like this:

```
O2.CustomerID AS Cust2,
COUNT(*) AS OverlappingProd
FROM (SELECT O.CustomerID, OD.ProductID
    FROM Orders AS O
    JOIN OrderDetails AS OD
    ON OD.orderid = o.orderid) AS O1
    JOIN(SELECT O.CustomerID, OD.ProductID
    FROM Orders AS O
    JOIN OrderDetails AS OD
    ON OD.orderid = o.orderid) AS O2
ON O2.ProductID = O1.ProductID 
AND O2.CustomerID > O1.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
O1.CustomerID,
O2.CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Is there a way to answer it not using the JOIN function? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: `JOIN` is not a function, it is an *operator*.  Other than doing something silly like replacing `JOIN` with `,`, I think this requires `JOIN`s for any sensible data model.

Comment: You really need JOIN, but let me ask this... if you have 5 people (A-E) who order part "X", do you want all combinations of people?  ie: AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE and DE?  Or do you just want all people A-E who ordered part X.  Is there a big reason for ALL combinations?  Imagine 50 people order same part...

Comment: The question doesn't say "without using joins" so why are you going down that path?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way of doing this without any joins.  You can express this in SQL using `cross join` and `exists`, so the following comes close:

```
select c1.customerid, c2.customerid,
       (select count(*)
        from products p
        where exists (select 1
                      from orderdetails od
                      where od.productid = p.productid and
                            exists (select 1
                                    from orders o
                                    where o.orderid = od.orderid and
                                          o.customerid = c1.customerid
                                   )
                     ) and
              exists (select 1
                      from orderdetails od
                      where od.productid = p.productid and
                            exists (select 1
                                    from orders o
                                    where o.orderid = od.orderid and
                                          o.customerid = c2.customerid
                                   )
                     )
        ) as num_products
from customers c1 cross join
     customers c2
where c1.customerid < c2.customerid;
```

Although this syntax will work in many databases, the nested correlation clauses are not supported in MySQL.  So, even accepting the `CROSS JOIN`, this does not work in MySQL.

The reason why a `JOIN` seems necessary is to get two independent customer ids in the result set.